# How to Open a File in Sublime3 from the Command Line on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, symlink

I was following some intructions online to set up a link so that I can open a file in sublime from my terminal.

I cd into `/usr/local/bin` I see brew and subl.

Then, I followed the instructions to set up the symbolic link.

In the terminal, I typed `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl`

Then I saw  `File exists` in the terminal

However, when I tried to `subl index.html`, 
I saw this message `command not found`.

Please advise

Comment: You may want `ln -sf` to force an overwrite, if it was already there.  What does `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep subl` show?

Comment: @Brian it showed sth like blah blah 1 root admin...

Comment: I was more interested in the part that shows the symlink...   `blah -> blah`

Comment: If you are in `/usr/local/bin`, use `./subl`, or preferably set your PATH to include `/usr/local/bin` always if you use **homebrew**.

Comment: Please run `echo $PATH | pbcopy` to copy your PATH, then click `edit` under your question and paste in the PATH. Then run `ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep subl | pbcopy` and paste that in too and you shall have your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you so much for all the answers. I found out that it was an administrative restriction because I was using a work laptop. I resolved it by re-installing sublime text using homebrew. Now, it's working fine.

`brew cask install sublime-text`

Thanks again.

Comment: Installing with brew also worked for me instantly on OS Sierra. I recommend that solution.

Answer (score 3):

First up, check your own $PATH by running: echo $PATH. It should return something like this

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in the path

Then run

`ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl`

Note that the directory sublime text 3 is in is

`"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`

and not

`"/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`

Which is what you ran. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did echo $PATH, and everything was fine. After I ran ```ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl```, it showed "file exists"

Answer (score 2):

It's not due to administrative restriction and you don't have to re-install sublime text.

As `File exists` suggests, the file has already exist, that's why your typing doesn't work.

Run `rm /usr/local/bin/subl` first to delete the exist file.

Then run `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl` should solve your problem.

---

Take me for example, 
my app is named `Sublime Text 3` instead of `Sublime Text`.

I ran `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl` as people suggest.

It didn't work due to the wrong path while the subl file created.
So I had to delete the existed file using `rm /usr/local/bin/subl`.

Then ran `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl` instead.

All things work now!!!

Comment: Thanks, for me, it's working for Sublime Text 2; ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

Answer (score 0):

I am on El capitan and what worked for me was
running ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"

- This only works if you check how your extension is named under info
- Also on the terminal you can't call sublime because you created it as subl instead so you have to write that in terminal

and then in terminal running subl . (to open a file )